# Keep getting a " JavaScript heap out of memory" on Digital Ocean running Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) x64 MERN Stack Next.js

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, digital-ocean, mern

So I made some changes to my  Next.js site on digital ocean, and I try to run sudo npm run build to build it, but I keep getting this error:

```
[230305:0x4a81f70]    83420 ms: Mark-sweep 485.9 (491.2) -> 485.7 (492.2) MB, 4015.7 / 1.8 ms  (average mu = 0.099, current mu = 0.009) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[230305:0x4a81f70]    87013 ms: Mark-sweep 486.6 (492.2) -> 486.4 (492.7) MB, 3574.2 / 11.8 ms  (average mu = 0.051, current mu = 0.004) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x140dc19]
    1: StubFrame [pc: 0x140eaed]
Security context: 0x3b4afa0408d1 <JSObject>
    2: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [0x2c959140c6c9] [/home/Dylancougar/massnow-frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/terser/bundle.min.js:~1] [pc=0x1f71ab556e46](this=0x0eeca6ec04b1 <undefined>)
    3: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [0x2c959140c749] [/home/Dylancougar/massnow-frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compi...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xa1a640 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa1aa4c node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xb9a62e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xb9a9a9 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xd57c25  [node]
 6: 0xd582b6 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [node]
 7: 0xd64b75 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xd65a25 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 9: 0xd684dc v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
10: 0xd2eefb v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
11: 0x10714ce v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
12: 0x140dc19  [node]
Aborted (core dumped)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! frontend@1.0.0 build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-11-30T01_18_08_999Z-debug.log
```

Some of the steps I tried in regards to resolving this issue, deleting the package.lock file, and node_modules folder and reinstalling that folder. I tried increasing the memory in the terminal. I tried increasing it to 8 gb `export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"`. I can run npm run build fine on my PC with no problems, and I wasn't having any problems with this script last week on my digital ocean droplet.

The problem just appeared seemingly out of the blue yesterday. This is what I get when viewing the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.15
3 info using node@v12.22.7
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle frontend@1.0.0~prebuild: frontend@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle frontend@1.0.0~build: frontend@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle frontend@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle frontend@1.0.0~build: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/Dylancougar/massnow-frontend/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle frontend@1.0.0~build: CWD: /home/Dylancougar/massnow-frontend
10 silly lifecycle frontend@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'next build' ]
11 silly lifecycle frontend@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 134  signal: null
12 info lifecycle frontend@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: frontend@1.0.0 build: `next build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 134
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1022:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid frontend@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/Dylancougar/massnow-frontend
16 verbose Linux 5.4.0-88-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.22.7
19 verbose npm  v6.14.15
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 134
22 error frontend@1.0.0 build: `next build`
22 error Exit status 134
23 error Failed at the frontend@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 134, true ]
```

And the Node version the I'm using on Digital Ocean is v12.22.7. Would anyone happen to know any other steps I can try?

Comment: how much memory did you allocate in your Digital Ocean Droplet? or are you using Digital Ocean App?

Comment: It says I have 1GB memory / 25 GB disk, on my Droplet dashboard. I used the export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192" command to try to allocate more space still the same error